# adTempus - trying to create a complicated schedule for a certain task

Tags: windows, task-scheduler, scheduler, job-scheduler

We've (that is, to say, my client) implemented the Windows-platform scheduling software adTempus, and have a task with a peculiar schedule.

The task needs to run on the 31st day of the month, but of course only in months that have 31 days, and only if the 31st does not fall on a weekend, a holiday, or a day when the Federal Reserve is closed.

For example, if today was 6/29/2010, the next time the task should run is 8/31/2010, because 7/31/2010 is a Saturday and June doesn't have 31 days.

I haven't been able to configure adTempus in a way to allow me to do this. I can restrict things by day, but the options list contains days 1 - 30, and then has a "31/Last" option that uses the last day of the month if there aren't 31 days in it. This means that when my task shouldn't run until 8/31/2010, it wants to run it on 6/30/2010. We already have a calendar to exclude the holidays, but the whole "31/Last" really throws everything off. I think they really need to have a "31" option and a separate "Last" option. Anyway...

I think the only way this will actually work is to create a Holiday schedule where the only days that aren't holidays are the days that the task should run.

Another option would be to write a simple PowerShell script that contains the logic to make the decision (I don't need any help with that), set that up as a job, and then make our actual job dependent on that script succeeding, but I'd like to use the calendars in the scheduler if I can.

Does anybody have any adTempus experience that could possibly help me out?

Comment: Not for nothing, but if I had this sort of ultra-specific task requirement, I'd check very carefully any new package I implemented.  Your best bet would be to contact them, I think.